# Using Hibernate to create column name and value from a hashmap

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Use case: 
I have a table with say 20 columns. I am using hibernate to create columns and enter values in them. Whenever I add a column, I have to write code, like

```
@Column(name = "ColumnName")
private Double varThatStoresThisColumnValue;
```

Everything good so far.

As the number of columns are going to increase say 50 or 100 or more, this class will increase and secondly I have to write the similar code for all the 50 or 100  variables (columns).

Question: Is it possible that I give a hashmap to hibernate, and hibernate should use key as column name and value as value for that column. As this will be so generic and will save me adding the variables (plus their get/set, equals, hashcode, toString etc.)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting that you will be constantly adding new columns to the table, then you should probably review your design to see if they would not be rows in a table instead of columns. That way, each new variable would be inserted in the table as a new record.

Comment: I agree with that. I consider it when initially designing the schema but due to some reasons, I could not go with that. But appreciate bringing in that perspective.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible you must declare your mapping either by adding the annotation to the attributes of your model class or via an xml mapping file. You have the choice As @Jihed Amine you should review your way of designing your model, 50 persistable attributes is too much for one model class.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to achieve what you want but not via updating same table schema. Check following class diagram with my comments:

[image]

So the advantages of this solutions is dynamic and scalable design but please be careful that this can come with the cost of **JOINs**